# Is there a relation between the ionization energy and the electron affinity?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, ions, energy, electron-affinity

I am aware of the definition and equation of IE and EA. I was wondering if there is a direct relation between this two quantities with the energy of the neutral specie.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, here's what I did (and I highly encourage everybody to do this along with this tutorial-style answer, just so you get the feel for prepping and looking at data from the world wild web).

### Data Acquisition

First, I went and copied the data from the tables at Wikipedia: [This one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_%28data_page%29) for the ionization energies and [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_%28data_page%29) for the electron affinities.

Next I had to clean up this data somewhat. For the electron affinity data I first had to get rid of all the unnecessary data columns. This was quickly done with `awk`:

```
   awk '{print $1, $2, $4}' raw-affinity.dat > affinity.dat
```

Next, I filtered out all the lines containing "-" and "?" using inverse search with `grep`:

```
    grep -v "?" affinity.dat | grep -v "-" > affinity2.dat
```

And finally I got rid of all these pesky statistical uncertainties with either one or two numbers between parentheses with `sed`:

```
    sed -e 's/(.)//g' -e 's/(..)//g' affinity2.dat > affinity3.dat
```

Now the data file looks somewhat like this:

```
1 H  0.754195
3 Li 0.618049
5 B  0.279723
6 C  1.262118
```

Now for the ionization data file. Since we only want to look at the first ionization energy we can scrap all the other data. Again, we'll use `awk` for this:

```
    awk '{print $1, $2}' raw-ionization.dat > ionization1.dat
```

Next we'll filter out all the data we don't want in there (again with `grep` and inverse searches):

```
    cat ionization1.dat | grep -v "use" | grep -v "WEL" | grep -v "talk" > ionization2.dat
```

In this file we still have some nasty linebreaks... So I loaded the file in `vim` and substituted the line break + "CRC" with nothing and saved it as `ionization3.dat`:

```
    :%s/\nCRC//g
    :saveas ionization3.dat
```

I also corrected the value for At manually in `vim` while I was at it, because it wasn't entered like all the other data in the Wikipedia table.

The ionization data file now looks like this:

```
1 H  13.59844
2 He 24.58741
3 Li 5.39172
4 Be 9.3227
```

All right, so we have the data nicely prepared and we're ready for the next step, which is

### Data Analysis Shenanigans

I did everything in `python` using the numpy and matplotlib packages. The code used can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/nMJRfKKY).

I didn't really notice some large trend of something you might expect. The plot gets pretty messy somehow. The darker the scatter points, the heavier the element.

[image: Ionization Energy vs Electron Affinity]

Maybe someone else notices a pattern that I'm missing right now.